# How to show only one image in homepage

Tags: images

I dont want to show image in my read_more function in homepage. read_more shows first 25 strings of my content. when I add image in the content it shows with the string inline. I don't want the image. Anyone know how to do it? here is my code below..

```
<div id="leadnewsbox" class="col-md-5 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
<?php 
$breakingcat = get_the_category_by_id($btimes['breaking-news-category']);
$breakingnews = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'category_name' => $breakingcat
));
while($breakingnews->have_posts()) : $breakingnews->the_post(); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('post-image'); ?></a>
    <div class="leadnewsboxtitle">
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <p><?php read_more(25); ?>...</p>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

```
// read_more function
function read_more($limit){
    $content = explode(' ', get_the_content());
    $less_content = array_slice($content, 0 , $limit);
    echo implode (' ', $less_content);
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are using a theme with custom functions in the loop.  Need to see the code behind `read_more()`.   This likely calls `the_excerpt()` for displaying the partial.  It's possible to filter that output and remove an `<img>` tag before output.

Comment: How can i remove the image sir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right, a function that truncates your text after stripping HTML is what you need.

What about using [wp_trim_words()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words):

```
<?php while($breakingnews->have_posts()) : $breakingnews->the_post(); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('post-image'); ?></a>
    <div class="leadnewsboxtitle">
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <p><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 60, '...' ); ?></p>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

General usage:

```
wp_trim_words( string $text, int $num_words = 55, string $more = null )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it works. but I used ream_more function so many times mistakenly. I don't want to change it. I found another solution like get_the_content from get_the excerpt and its working properly. thanks again man. You people are too much helpful.

Comment: You can keep it:

function read_more($limit)
{
    echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), $limit, '&hellip;' );
}

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found without changing the function.

```
// read_more function
function read_more($limit){
 $content = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt());
 $less_content = array_slice($content, 0 , $limit);
 echo implode (' ', $less_content);
}
```